# When I use RelationshipFrom() method in NeoModel, Python, get KeyError: '__file__'

Tags: python, neo4j, neomodel

I'm trying to make web server using Python, Neo4j, NeoModel and Heroku. And because I'm not familiar with NeoModel, I'm now trying to learn from [Github NeoModel Basic tutorial](https://github.com/robinedwards/neomodel). I have a trouble when I compile this code.

```
from neomodel import (StructuredNode, StringProperty, IntegerProperty,
    RelationshipTo, RelationshipFrom)

class Country(StructuredNode):
    code = StringProperty(unique_index=True, required=True)

    # traverse incoming IS_FROM relation, inflate to Person objects
    inhabitant = RelationshipFrom('Person', 'IS_FROM')


class Person(StructuredNode):
    name = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    age = IntegerProperty(index=True, default=0)

    # traverse outgoing IS_FROM relations, inflate to Country objects
    country = RelationshipTo(Country, 'IS_FROM')
```

And I got this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\someo_000\Desktop\a.py", line 11, in <module>
    class Person(StructuredNode):
  File "C:\Users\someo_000\Desktop\a.py", line 16, in Person
    country = RelationshipTo(Country, 'IS_FROM')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\neomodel\relationship_manager.py", line 287, in RelationshipTo
    return _relate(cls_name, OUTGOING, rel_type, cardinality, model)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\neomodel\relationship_manager.py", line 283, in _relate
    return RelationshipDefinition(rel_type, cls_name, direction, cardinality, model)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\neomodel\relationship_manager.py", line 218, in __init__
    self.module_file = sys._getframe(4).f_globals['__file__']
KeyError: '__file__'
```

I'm trying to do this using Heroku and local server
I set `NEO4J_REST_URL` environment variable in cmd in both case.
And in both case, I got same error.

If I delete these two lines

```
inhabitant = RelationshipFrom('Person', 'IS_FROM')
country = RelationshipTo(Country, 'IS_FROM')
```

I think it works well.

thank you for reading!

Comment: Trying putting the Country object reference inside quotes with the relationship to as well

inhabitant = RelationshipFrom('Person', 'IS_FROM')
country = RelationshipTo("Country", 'IS_FROM')